# Is Gwt PopupPanel method setPopupPosition overwritten when adding it to another Panel?

Tags: gwt, popuppanel

I'd like to set the position of my `PopupPanel` relative to the Panel I'm adding it to. However, the position I set with

```
popupPanel.setPopupPosition(750,230);
```

is ignored.

Is the method position overwritten when adding it to a panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *“add a `PopupPanel` to a panel”*. If you do that, then you're treating it like it's a `SimplePanel`, and it behaves almost like a `SimplePanel`; so yes `setPopupPosition` won't work, at least without some additional CSS applied.

If you want to show a `PopupPanel` relative to another element, use `setPopupPositionAndShow` and compute the position relative to the other element's absolute position.

Comment: Or, you can use myPopupPanel.showRelativeTo(myMainPanel);